# I need help optimizing BGR888 blitting to NSView

Tags: core-graphics, nsview, cgcontext, nsbitmapimagerep, vimage

This is best I've come up with for blitting a 24-bit BGR image out to an NSView.

I did trim a significant amount of CPU time by ensuring that the NSWindow host also had the same colorSpace.

I think there are 4 or 5 pixel copies going on here:

1. in the `vImage` conversion (required)
2. calling `CGDataProviderCreateWithData`
3. calling `CGImageCreate`
4. creating the `NSBitmapImageRep` bitmap
5. in the final blit with `drawInRect` (required)

**Anyone want to chime in on improving it?**

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
{
   // one-time setup code
   CGColorSpaceRef useColorSpace = nil; 
   int w = 1920;
   int h = 1080;
   [theWindow setColorSpace: [NSColorSpace genericRGBColorSpace]];
   // setup vImage buffers (not listed here)
   // srcBuffer is my 24-bit BGR image (malloc-ed to be w*h*3)
   // dstBuffer is for the resulting 32-bit RGBA image (malloc-ed to be w*h*4)

   ...
   // this is called @ 30-60fps
   if (!useColorSpace)
      useColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateWithName(kCGColorSpaceGenericRGB);
   vImage_Error err = vImageConvert_BGR888toRGBA8888(srcBuffer, NULL, 0xff, dstBuffer, NO, 0);

   CGDataProviderRef newProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL,dstBuffer->data,w*h*4,myReleaseProvider);
   CGImageRef myImageRGBA = CGImageCreate(w, h, 8, 32, w*4, useColorSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault | kCGImageAlphaLast, newProvider, NULL, false, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
   CGDataProviderRelease(newProvider);
   // store myImageRGBA in an array of frames (using NSObject wrappers) for later access (setNeedsDisplay:)
   ... 
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
   // this is called @ 30-60fps
   CGImageRef storedImage = ...;  // retrieve from array
   NSBitmapImageRep *repImg = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithCGImage:storedImage];
   CGRect myFrame = CGRectMake(0,0,CGImageGetWidth(storedImage),CGImageGetHeight(storedImage));
   [repImg drawInRect:myFrame fromRect:myFrame operation:NSCompositeCopy fraction:1.0 respectFlipped:TRUE hints:nil];

   // free image from array (not listed here)
}

// this is called when the CGDataProvider is ready to release its data
void myReleaseProvider (void *info, const void *data, size_t size)
{
    if (data)  {
        free((void *)data);
        data=nil;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB instead of genericRGB to avoid colorspace conversion inside CG. Use kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast instead of kCGImageAlphaLast since we know alpha is opaque to allow for a copy instead of a blend.

After you make those changes, it would be useful to run an Instruments time profile on it to show where the time is going.